# Using jquery to append an attribute of a parent tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <strong>
        <a href="link.php?category=1&link=apple">
            <span>string</span>
        </a>
    </strong>
</div>

<div>
    <strong>
        <a href="link.php?category=2&link=banana">
            <span>string</span>
        </a>
    </strong>
</div>
```

I want to append a link inside of each div that contains a span with "string". That link will have as its id the link parameter of the href attribute of the link that contains the span so for example:

```
<div>
    <strong>
        <a href="link.php?category=1&link=apple">
            <span>string</span>
        </a>
    </strong>
    <a class="details" id="apple_details">Show Details +</a>
</div>

<div>
    <strong>
        <a href="link.php?category=2&link=banana">
            <span>string</span>
        </a>
    </strong>
    <a class="details" id="banana_details">Show Details +</a>
</div>
```

What I have so far is this:

```
$("span:contains('string')").parent().parent().parent().append('<a class="details" id="details">Show Details +</a>');
```

How do I get the href attribute of the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("a[href*='link=']").each(function() {
  if( $(this).text() !== "string" ) return; // Do nothing.
  var id = $(this).attr("href").match(/[?&]link=([^&]+)/)[1];
  if( id ) $(this).closest("div").append(`<a class="details" id="${id}_details">Show Details +</a>`);
});
```

```html
<div>
   <a href="link.php?category=1&link=apple"><span><b>string</b></span></a>
</div>
<div>
   <a href="link.php?category=2&link=banana"><span><b>string</b></span></a>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works for me, so you're setting {id} here and then if it exists, passing it to the append?

Comment: @pg. exactly. Extra precaution. *if the `.match` fails, than don't do the append stuff.*

Answer (score 3):

Use `.each()` to loop over all the spans, get the attribute of the parent, and then append to the DIV.

```
$("span:contains('string')").each(function() {
    var href=$(this).parent().attr("href");
    var link = href.match(/&link=([^&]+)/)[1];
    $(this).closest("div").append($("<a>", {
        "class": "details",
        id: link + "_details",
        text: "Show Details"
    }));
});
```

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan 1, 6) fixed; 2-4, 7) That's a problem with the problem specification, I assume his HTML is consistent; 5) I've never heard of this, I expect jQuery to deal with such compatibility issues